# Angularfire: How to wait for firebase to load?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, firebase, angularfire, firebase-authentication

In my ionic (angular) app,

1. How can I wait for firebase to load ?
2. I want to change app state based on user is authenticated or not.

Currently, `firebase.auth().currentUser` returns as null.

```
$ionicPlatform.ready(function(){
    firebase.auth().currentUser --> null
});
```

But

```
.controller('MyController', function($scope, $ionicPopup, $firebaseAuth) {
    $scope.$on('$ionicView.afterEnter', function(e) {
        firebase.auth().currentUser --> is valid     
    });
});
```

Comment: See the documentation on [retrieving authentication state](https://github.com/firebase/angularfire/blob/master/docs/guide/user-auth.md#retrieving-authentication-state) and [authenticating with routers](https://github.com/firebase/angularfire/blob/master/docs/guide/user-auth.md#authenticating-with-routers).

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use `$loaded` function which returns a promise which is resolved when the initial server data has been downloaded.

```
var ref = new Firebase("https://<YOUR_FIREBASE_APP>.firebaseio.com/foo");
var obj = new $firebaseObject(ref);
obj.$loaded().then(function() {
    console.log(obj.$value); // "bar"
});
```

more info: https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/guide/synchronized-objects.html